# Prove that if p is prime and if the order of G is a power of p,then G has non-trivial center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Problem**

Prove that if $ p$ is prime and if the order of $G$ is a power of$ p$,then $G$ has non-trivial center.

Proof using class equation :

$|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum|G:C(a)|$,
where the sum run over representative s of all conjugacy classes with more than one element. But $|G:C(a)|=|G|/|C(a)|$,so each term in $\sum|G:C(a)|$ has the form $p^k$ with $k\geq 1$ . Hence p divides |Z(G)| since$ |Z(G)= |G|-\sum|G:C(a)|$  and $ p $ divides each term on the right.

**Doubt**

How to proof this theorem using action ?

My attempt was to right *Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem* in terms of homomorphism and proceed from there.

**Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem**

For each$ x\in X$ ,the correspondence $g(x)\to gG_x$ is a bijection between $G(x)$ and the set of left cosets of $G_x$ in $G$, where $G_x$ is the stabiliser of $x$ and $G(x)$ is the *orbit* of $x$.

*My understanding of action*

An  action  of a  group $ G$  on  a  set  X is  a  homomorphism from  $G$  to  $S_X$

Comment: A group acts on itself by conjugation. By the orbit-stabiliser theorem, orbits have size dividing the order of the group, so, in the case of a $p$-group, powers of $p$. This means that the number of fixed points (orbits of size 1) is divisible by $p$, but this is exactly the set of central elements.

Comment: Note that this is essentially the same proof as with the class equation, just using a slightly different language.

Comment: @verret i can see now. Thanks.